# Finding probability of a point using bivariate copula density

Tags: density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, copula, density-estimation

I have a data in the form $\textbf{N} \times 2$. I am using bivariate copula to model the joint density of this distribution. Firstly, I fit 2 marginal distributions independently on each column of the data, then converted the data to $[0,1]^{2}$ space using the CDF of each of those marginal distributions. On that converted data, I fitted a Gaussian copula.

The next step is to compute the density of any arbitrary data that may not be in the initial data. I use the same marginal distributions to compute cdf values for this new data. And then compute the PDF of the copula over those cdf values.

However, if this new datapoint has a value in either(or both) of the columns greater than the range of the initial data - it would lead to the input to copula's pdf function as (1.0, 1.0) denoting highest CDF - which produces high density. This high density makes the new data point to seem as a point coming out of the same initial distribution, we are modeling, which clearly it is not.

Am I missing something in computing probability density of this new point? Does the copula density need to be multiplied by the marginal probabilities?

Comment: The approach you are using depends strongly on exactly how you perform the fitting.  What methods are you using?

Comment: Method: I am using AIC based selection of fitting copula. 
Specifically, I am using BiCopSelect functionality in VineCopula library to fit the copula.

Comment: How do you estimate the marginal distributions in the first place?  This is key.

Comment: I am trying a huge variety of distributions, and choosing the one which best fits the marginal. Specifically, I am using the fitter library in Python to iterate through a lot of distributions.

Comment: That doesn't sound consistent with your description.  If it's the case, then those fits ought to project some probability out beyond the limits of your data, but you write as if they haven't done that.  That's why we need details.

Comment: I just compute copula density on the CDFs - so for a point outside the range of the initial marginal distribution fits - CDF comes out to be 1.0 or 0.0 (based on the side of the range). And when only these CDFs are plugged into the vine PDF function, it turns out to be really high. I am guessing I should multiply it with the PDF I am getting from marginals to get the exact pdf value of the given out-of-marginal range unseen point, thus enough to classify it as outlier.

Comment: Perhaps when you said CDF you really meant empirical CDF? If, say, you fit your marginal distribution assuming it is a Gaussian distribution, then new point cannot be "out-of-range"; judging from the description you gave, it sounds like you were using functions such as `ecdf()` in R to measure the probability of a new input where it will give `0.0` or `1.0` for an input that exceeds the range of the original data used to "train" the empirical CDF. Also, what kind of distributions do you have in your candidate distribution list?